# SQL Injection after Order By

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, sql-injection

I am working on a SQL Injection fixes. I modified my DAO layer to parametrize my criteria(Prepared statement). 
On screen I have a Grid which allows to sort the data. My question after "Order by xyz", will there be any SQL Injection. 
Please Note : "xyz" is send by UI.

```
For Example
        Normal : Select employeeNumber, employeeName from employee order by employeeNumber
        Injection : Select employeeNumber, employeeName from employee order by employeeNumber;
                                                          delete from employee

At the DAO layer I am using Spring, Hibernate

Do I need to handle the ";" while setting dynamic Order By in query.
```

In short : How to handle SQL Injection for dynamic Order by clause.

Comment: Toyr question is not clear (or complete). Where/how is the user inout(`xyz`?) being used in the SQL?

Comment: @Nivas, xyz is Column. And in UI there is a Grid(Table like View). User can click on the Header of the Grid to sort table based on the column. Our Frame work, takes the "Column Name" from the Grid and do Order by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically change the order by criteria, than 
[JPA Criteria API with type-safe Metamodel](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-typesafejpa/) is your best friend.

Comment: I went through this API but Criteria API do not support Native SQL, we got many native SQL in the application. Is there any way that Criteria can used for native SQL.

Comment: Then [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual-single-page/#order-by-clause) is the right tool for you.

Comment: JOOQ is a good tool, but I have a Hibernate in my application and in many scenarios it is very difficult to use model objects. And now to get JOOQ will take a much time and require more testing at the application level.